# How to compare user input to corresponding model field django

Tags: python, html, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm trying to make learning app for myself and part of my plan is to make a quiz module.

My problem is, that I don't know how to compare user answer with the correct answer that's stored in the model.

Now, the only thing I've tried (except reading docs and stack overflow) was to inject the related model question inside of my HTML to later use in views.py, but from the beginning I felt like that's not the way it should work, so I guess I have to reorganize my models/forms or inside of views.py there is some way to query database for that specific model instance that I don't know.

Here is my code

Models:

```
class Question(models.Model):
        question = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
        answer = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question
```

Forms:

```
class Answer(forms.Form):
    answer = forms.CharField()
```

Views:

```
def quiz(request):
    questions = Question.objects.order_by('question')
    form = Answer()
    context_dict = {'form':form,'questions':questions}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Answer(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
        #Here I want to make the comparison
            pass
    return render(request,"quiz_app/quiz.html",context_dict)
```

HTML:

```
<table>
        {% for q in questions %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ q.question }}</td>       
                <form method="POST">
                    <td>{{ form.answer }}</td>
                    {% csrf_token %}
                <td>
                    <input type="submit" value="submit">
                </td>
                </form>
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: You need to link your ```Answer``` form to the question. Have you tried using a ```ModelForm``` for your answer with the ```Question``` as model and an additional field for the user answer?

Comment: I've tried to do that, but that was not a successfull try at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the question_id with the post request and then get the question instance and compare the results. 
HTML:

```html
<form method="POST">
     <td>{{ form.answer }}</td>
      {% csrf_token %}
      <input type="hidden" name="q_id" value="{{ q.id }}" />
      <td>
          <input type="submit" value="submit">
      </td>
</form>
```

views:

```py
def quiz(request):
    questions = Question.objects.order_by('question')
    form = Answer()
    context_dict = {'form':form,'questions':questions}
    if request.method == 'POST':
        instance = Question.objects.get(id=request.POST['q_id'])
        form = Answer(request.POST, instance=instance)

        if form.is_valid():
        #Here I want to make the comparison
            if request.POST.get("answer").strip() == instance.answer:
                # used strip() to remove whitespace before and after the text.
                # other logic. 
    return render(request,"quiz_app/quiz.html",context_dict)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't know how to grab HTML input in views, so thank you again. Now, when I've tried to implement it, I got an error "TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'instance' ". I've fixed it by changing the logic, but anyway I'm curious , how to do that?

Comment: ok, my bad. your `class Answer(forms.Form):` should inherit from `forms.ModelForm`. Then only you can pass the instance. So your form should be `class Answer(forms.ModelForm):`